# Supervisord: how to source rvm, and bundle exec to launch a rails script?

Tags: ruby, rvm, bundler, supervisord

I'm trying to manage a ruby script with **supervisord** but because I haven't fully understood how RVM works I have not been able to do it properly.

Normally I would just do the following:

```
# sourcing of rvm done automatically on ssh login
cd /var/rails/myapp
RAILS_ENV="production" bundle exec ./script/backgroundrb
```

But with the following configuration file I cannot do it:

```
[program:owgm]
directory=/var/rails/owgm
command=bundle exec ./script/backgroundrb
environment=RAILS_ENV="production"
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/bundle:$PATH"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I get the following error:

> *Could not load OpenSSL. You must recompile Ruby with OpenSSL support or change the sources in your Gemfile from 'https' to 'http'.
>   Instructions for compiling with OpenSSL using RVM are available at
>   rvm.io/packages/openssl.*

It looks like I'm not managing to get the right ruby environment.

I thought setting the path would work, because if I do:

```
which bundle
```

I get: **/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/bundle**

But I'm not even sure of what is happening.

With Python I would do something like:

```
command=/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/script.py
```

Is there something similar I could do with ruby?

The output of **rvm info** is:

```
ree-1.8.7-2012.02:

  system:
    uname:       "Linux owtb2 3.2.0-44-generic #69-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 16 17:35:01 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
    system:      "ubuntu/12.04/x86_64"
    bash:        "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)"
    zsh:         " => not installed"

  rvm:
    version:      "rvm 1.21.3 (stable) by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.io/]"
    updated:      "4 months 4 days 3 hours 54 minutes 35 seconds ago"

  ruby:
    interpreter:  "ruby"
    version:      "1.8.7"
    date:         "2012-02-08"
    platform:     "x86_64-linux"
    patchlevel:   "2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358"
    full_version: "ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux], MBARI 0x6770, Ruby Enterprise Edition 2012.02"

  homes:
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02"
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02"

  binaries:
    ruby:         "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/ruby"
    irb:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/irb"
    gem:          "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin/gem"
    rake:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin/rake"

  environment:
    PATH:         "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games"
    GEM_HOME:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02"
    GEM_PATH:     "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global"
    MY_RUBY_HOME: "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02"
    IRBRC:        "/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/.irbrc"
    RUBYOPT:      ""
    gemset:       ""
```

Comment: With the first configuration, what is the output of `rvm info`?
By setting the PATH in that way, you are bypassing rvm and forcing the use of ruby-ree-1.8.7 bins...

Comment: added output of rvm info

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to the suggestion of @mpapis I have been able to figure out something that works.

His suggestion unfortunately didn't, but he was right in the fact that I had to look in **/usr/local/rvm/wrappers**

This is the working config file:

```
[program:owgm]
directory=/var/rails/owgm
command=/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2012.02/bundle exec ./script/backgroundrb
environment=RAILS_ENV="production"
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Answer (score 3):

it should be:

```
PATH="/usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ree-1.8.7-2012.02@global:$PATH"
```

Comment: near.. I had to tweak something and got it working. Thx for the suggestion abut the wrappers folder. What is that?

Comment: in the wrappers directory you can find most common binaries for ruby wrapped in a script that loads proper environment and then loads the binary, in case you need to load other binary then one available already you can run: `rvm wrapper ruby-version --no-links binary_name`.